# Adjust brightness in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I want to be able to adjust the brightness in my windows phone 8 programmatically using c#. What are the possible ways to do that?

Comment: Screen birghtness is only adjustable from settings by the user.

Answer (score 1):

API for brightness is unavailibale.

However there is a possible workarond:
Overlay your view with black border and change the opacity of that border.

Answer (score 0):

Like most global settings on Windows Phone, the brightness of the screen cannot be changed from third-party applications.